# mypy does not recognize attrs: Cannot determine type of 's'

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-attrs

```
> pip3.8 list
Package           Version
----------------- -------
attrs             19.3.0
mypy              0.761
mypy-extensions   0.4.3
pip               19.3.1
setuptools        42.0.2
typed-ast         1.4.1
typing-extensions 3.7.4.1
wheel             0.33.6
```

```
> mypy --version
mypy 0.761
```

```
# types.py
import typing
import attr

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True, slots=True, frozen=True)
class Test:
    b: bool = False
```

```
> mypy types.py
types.py:4: error: Cannot determine type of 's'
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Do I need to install something else for `attrs` support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh this is odd and maybe a bug in mypy! Rename `types.py` into something else and it will work:

```
$ mypy types.py
types.py:4: error: Cannot determine type of 's'
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
$ mv types.py t.py
$ mypy t.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Computers! `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: I created a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8351). Thanks, I probably would have thought to try that.

Comment: it probably uses stdlib [module `types`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html) under-the-hood which gets overwritten by user-module with same name

Comment: That's possible. `attrs` does some gross string comparisons when detecting ClassVars too because actually importing it is very slow.